# Unable get message on IOS from firebase console with phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase

i have successfully implemented Firebase cloud messaging in my phonegap app with phonegap-plugin-push on IOS, i am receiving token from Firebase on register event, i print it in alert message and it shows me token.
Below is my code

```js
   function onDeviceReady(){
           var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                  "senderID": "29271112133",
      sound: true,
      vibrate: true
           },
            "ios": {"senderID": "29271112133","alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"},
            "windows": {}
        });


        push.on('registration', function(data)
                {
                globalpushtoken1 = data.registrationId;
                alert("Token IS HERE..  "+globalpushtoken1);
                   
                     checktoken(data.registrationId);

                });


        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            if(data.additionalData.coldstart){
                  if(data.title=="New Offer !"){
                   window.location.replace("#offerspage"); }
             }

         });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
          alert("Push Error");
            console.log("push error");
        });
```

Now the problem is when i try to send some test message from firebase console and select User segment and select my app and send message it shows message status as completed however i dont get any notification on real device, and if i send the message to specific device using token of that device then it shows status as 
FAILED Unregistered registration token " I am new to firebase and phonegap, please help me resolve this.
[firebase console after sending message manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy1hX.png)

Comment: no one seems to be interested in this question :(